# Facebook iOS SDK , exception against FBSession, *** Assertion failure in -[FBSession close]

Tags: ios, facebook, session, ios5, facebook-ios-sdk

I'm using facebook sdk 3.0.8 for ios. when i try to login with facebook it works fine but sometimes when i try to login after logging out then app is being crashed.

here is exception message

```
*** Assertion failure in -[FBSession close], /Users/jacl/src/ship/ios-sdk/src/FBSession.m:342
```

can you please tell me where i'm going wrong?

**Here is code inside AppDelegate**

```
    - (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application
            openURL:(NSURL *)url
  sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication
         annotation:(id)annotation {
    // attempt to extract a token from the url
    return [FBSession.activeSession handleOpenURL:url]; 
}


- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application {

    [self.session close];
}

#pragma mark Template generated code


// FBSample logic
// It is possible for the user to switch back to your application, from the native Facebook application, 
// when the user is part-way through a login; You can check for the FBSessionStateCreatedOpenening
// state in applicationDidBecomeActive, to identify this situation and close the session; a more sophisticated
// application may choose to notify the user that they switched away from the Facebook application without
// completely logging in
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {
    /*
     Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the background, optionally refresh the user interface.
     */


    // FBSample logic
    // this means the user switched back to this app without completing a login in Safari/Facebook App
    if (self.session.state == FBSessionStateCreatedOpening) {
        // BUG: for the iOS 6 preview we comment this line out to compensate for a race-condition in our
        // state transition handling for integrated Facebook Login; production code should close a
        // session in the opening state on transition back to the application; this line will again be
        // active in the next production rev
        //[self.session close]; // so we close our session and start over
    }
}
```

**Code Inside View Controller**

```
-(IBAction)connectWithFacebook{
         DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TotallyCuteAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];
        if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen && (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated))
        {
            appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
        }

        NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                @"publish_actions",
                                @"email",
                                nil];
        //app crashes here
        [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES 
                                  completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                      if (session.isOpen) 
                                      {
                                        NSLog(@"LoginVC->Session is open");
                                        appDelegate.session=session; 
                                        [userDefaults setObject:appDelegate.session.accessToken forKey:@"facebook_token"];
                                        [userDefaults setObject:paramFBId forKey:@"facebook_id"];


                                      }
                                      else
                                      {
                                          NSLog(@"LoginVC->Session is not open");
                                      }
                                  }//end completionHandler
         ];

}




-(IBAction)logout:(id)sender{
    DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TotallyCuteAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]; 

    if (appDelegate.session.isOpen) {
        [appDelegate.session closeAndClearTokenInformation];

        [[NSUserDefaults userDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"facebook_id"];
        [[NSUserDefaults userDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"facebook_token"];
      } 
}
```

**Edit:**

removed the following code and now it works fine

```
  if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen && (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated))
            {
                appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            }
```

here is updated code

```
 -(IBAction)connectWithFacebook{
        if ([InternetChecker isConnected]) 
        {
            DemoAppDelegate *appDelegate = (TotallyCuteAppDelegate *) [[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate];

    /* Removed following if block
           if (!appDelegate.session.isOpen && (appDelegate.session.state != FBSessionStateCreated))
            {
                appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
            }
    */
            NSArray *permissions = [[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:
                                    @"publish_actions",
                                    @"email",
                                    nil];

            [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions allowLoginUI:YES 
                                      completionHandler:^(FBSession *session, FBSessionState status, NSError *error) {
                                          if (session.isOpen) 
                                          {
                                            NSLog(@"LoginVC->Session is open");
                                            appDelegate.session=session; 
                                            [userDefaults setObject:appDelegate.session.accessToken forKey:@"facebook_token"];
                                            [userDefaults setObject:paramFBId forKey:@"facebook_id"];


                                          }
                                          else
                                          {
                                              NSLog(@"LoginVC->Session is not open);
                                          }
                                      }//end completionHandler
             ];
        } 
    }
```

Comment: you are misusing the API, please see my answer for an explanation

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at FBSession.m, the assertion in `close` is as follows:

```
NSAssert(self.affinitizedThread == [NSThread currentThread], @"FBSession: should only be used from a single thread");
```

Are you calling `-close` from a thread other than the one you created the session on?

Looking into this further. You're misusing the API. You are creating

```
appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
```

but then you are calling

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions ...
```

which creates an entirely new session. Meaning you never opened `appDelegate.session`, and therefore you should not try to close it. What you should be doing instead is the following:

```
[FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions ...
appDelegate.session = [FBSession activeSession];
```

Another option is to just do:

```
appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];
[appDelegate.session openWithCompletionHandler: ...
```

Comment: Thanks yfrancis , i am trying your suggestions, and i think i'm about solve my problem :)

Comment: should i not use appDelegate.session = [[FBSession alloc] init];  in whole application??
I was just following some facebook sample login demo and it was FBSession alloc was there

Comment: well not if you use `openActiveSessionWithPermissions` which does: `FBSession *session = [[[FBSession alloc] initWithPermissions:permissions] autorelease];` which creates a whole new session. I've updated my answer with a more correct solution

Comment: Thank you so much yfrancis.  i've updated code now works fine.

initialized appDelegate.session in completionHandler.    appDelegate.session=session;

Comment: I am using new FacebookSdk and it has no FBSession.m file

Answer (score 3):

You should perform your code on the main thread

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [FBSession openActiveSessionWithPermissions:permissions
                                   allowLoginUI:YES
                              completionHandler:^(FBSession *session,
                                                  FBSessionState status,
                                                  NSError *error) {
                                                       // do something
                                                  }];
});
```